# how to update and add entries with attributes to a xml file, sorted by date?

Tags: c#, xml

I want to store my logged keystrokes with their id and the count by each day to an xml file. The keystrokes are temporaray saved in an Hashtable. I want to move the collected data from the hashtable every 20 sec to the xml file. The Programm should create a new Entry with the Attribute Keyid and the collected amount under the entry Element with the current date. If an Key already exsits, the programm should update the count of this key by adding the new count to the old one. Here is my example XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<entrys>
  <entry date="2015_08_31">
    <key id ="4">78</key>
    <key id ="99">4</key>
    <key id ="210">7</key>
  </entry>
  <entry date="2015_08_30">
    <key id ="4">8</key>
    <key id ="9">6</key>
    <key id ="210">8</key>
  </entry>
</entrys>
```

Working with c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this as follows:

1. Use XDocument to load your XML file.
2. Convert your data to a dictionary of dictionaries.
3. Merge the new data into the dictionary of dictionaries.
4. Convert the dictionary of dictionaries back to XML.

The following code demonstrates. It expects as input a file called "D:\TEST\INPUT.XML" containing the XML code from your question.

If creates as output a file called "D:\TEST\OUTPUT.XML" containing the merged data. Edit the filenames to suit.

Hopefully you can run this code under the debugger to get an idea of how it works.

Given this input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<entrys>
  <entry date="2015_08_31">
    <key id ="4">78</key>
    <key id ="99">4</key>
    <key id ="210">7</key>
  </entry>
  <entry date="2015_08_30">
    <key id ="4">8</key>
    <key id ="9">6</key>
    <key id ="210">8</key>
  </entry>
</entrys>
```

Running the code gives the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<entrys>
  <entry date="2015_08_31">
    <key id="4">78</key>
    <key id="99">14</key>
    <key id="210">7</key>
    <key id="300">20</key>
  </entry>
  <entry date="2015_08_30">
    <key id="4">8</key>
    <key id="9">6</key>
    <key id="210">8</key>
  </entry>
</entrys>
```

The code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace Demo
{
    internal class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        private static void Main()
        {
            var doc = XDocument.Load("D:\\TEST\\INPUT.XML"); // Assume you have the XML file stored here.

            // Convert existing entries to a dictionary of dictionaries: 
            // So dict[date][key] == count

            var entries = doc.Elements("entrys").Elements("entry");

            var existing = entries.ToDictionary
            (
                item => item.Attribute("date").Value, 
                item => item.Descendants("key").ToDictionary
                (
                    key => (int)key.Attribute("id"),
                    key => (int)key
                )
            );

            // SAMPLE DATA: Add new items for specific date.

            string date = "2015_08_31";

            var newData = new Dictionary<int, int>();

            newData[99]  = 10;
            newData[300] = 20;

            addEntriesForDate(date, existing, newData);

            // Store back to XML.

            var xd = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", ""),
                new XElement("entrys", existing.Select(kvp => 
                    new XElement("entry", new XAttribute("date", kvp.Key), kvp.Value.Select(key =>
                        new XElement("key", new XAttribute("id", key.Key), key.Value 
             ))))));

            xd.Save("D:\\TEST\\OUTPUT.XML");
        }

        private static void addEntriesForDate(string date, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, int>> existing, Dictionary<int, int> newData)
        {
            if (!existing.ContainsKey(date))
                existing[date] = new Dictionary<int, int>();

            var data = existing[date];

            foreach (var entry in newData)
            {
                if (data.ContainsKey(entry.Key))
                    data[entry.Key] += entry.Value;
                else
                    data[entry.Key] = entry.Value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sooooo much! That was exactly what i needed. Learning LINQ is my next Task on my to do list!!